# How to generate a three column data file in gnuplot

Tags: datatable, gnuplot, data-files, dollar-sign

its my first question in this community. I am running the following short script in gnuplot (5.2),

`set table "testable.txt"
plot '+' using 1:($1**2):($1**3)
unset table`

The resulting data file contains only two columns; first a series of numbers from -10 to 10, and second their squares (as expected), but the third column (which should be the cubes of entries in first column) is missing. How can I get that third column in my data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with table`. Check `help plot with table`.

```
set table "testable.txt"
plot '+' using 1:($1**2):($1**3) with table
unset table
```